# Почему происходит утечка памяти в приведенном примере?

Tags: node.js, сборщик-мусора, утечка-памяти

Следующий код имитирует загрузку и парсинг HTML. Выдергивает ссылки и сохраняет их в глобальном массиве.

Если он сохраняет ссылки как показано в строке "Вариант 1", то node начинает жрать память. ~ 1Гб на 30.000 ссылок
Если эту строку закомментировать и сохранять способом "Вариант 2", то все нормально, память растет, но понемногу, по мере увеличения массива ссылок - можно хоть миллион их сохранить.

Я не могу понять в чем разница, ведь в обоих случаях в массив сохраняется примитивная строка? 
Проверял всевозможными способами, вызов $().text() возвращает не объект в который он мог бы добавить ссылку на весь DOM и исходный текст в придачу, а именно строку. Но такое впечатление что все это как-то цепляется и сборщик мусора не может почистить память.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var _=require('lodash');
var links=[];

for (var i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    getS();
    console.log('%s links collected',links.length);
}


function getS() {
    var body='<body>';
    for(var i=0;i<20;i++) {
        body+='<a class="i-ljuser-username" href="#">'+Math.random()*100000+'</a>';
        while (body.length<15000*i) {
            body+='<span>+Math.random()*100000+</span>';
            }       
    }
    body+='</body>';
    var $=cheerio.load(body);
    var list=$('a.i-ljuser-username');
    _.forEach(list,function(item){
        links.push($(item).text()); //Вариант 1
        //links.push(($(item).text()+' ').trim()); //Вариант 2
    });
}
```

Comment: думаю, что делая `$(item).text()+' '` Вы явно кастуете к строке, которая "забывает о том, откудова она". А в первом случае виртуальная машина пытается сэкономить на копировании и добавляет не просто строку, а объект, который хоть и выглядит как строка, но помнит "слишком много".

Comment: Меня больше интересует именно в каких случаях виртуальная машина начинает так "экономить". Потому что шаманить таким вот образом над каждой строкой это какое-то извращение. Хорошо я наткнулся на ситуацию где это проявляется явно и быстро, а если нет?

Comment: Если хотите точно посмотреть, что жрет память, то можно снять хип дамп и заглянуть туда. `.text()` действительно может возвращать что-то, отличающееся от обычной строки.

Comment: **Меня больше интересует именно в каких случаях виртуальная машина начинает так "экономить".**

это очень сложный вопрос. и мой ответ короткий - хотите больше предсказуемости - используйте более предсказуемые языки. Либо углубляйтесь в изучение ноды.

Comment: Судя по исходному коду cheerio, там тоже используются строки, так что это какая-то нодовая мистика. Есть предположение, что garbage collector просто не отрабатывает, потому что еще не уперся в лимит, а второй пример каким-то образом триггерит его исполнение. Как именно снимались метрики об использовании оперативной памяти и доходило ли это дело когда-нибудь до out of memory-ошибки?

Comment: > доходило ли это дело когда-нибудь до out of memory-ошибки?
да

делал snapshot'ы кучи и загружал их в chrome.
Сhrome показывает что один снапшот, условно 10мб, второй 600Мб, но что именно там занимает столько места - не отображает

Comment: А если в первый вариант добавить toString() ?

Comment: И ещё, незнаю баг это или фича но в цикле whie функция Math.random()*100000 написана простой строкой.

Comment: @vnn198 я пробовал toString(), new String(), _.clone(), .substr(0) и даже +’’ - это абсолютно ничего не изменяло. Math.random - там где это просто строка некритично, это мусор остался. А вот там где формируются ссылки - важно. Если они одинаковые,  то нода что-то еще тихой сапой оптимизирует и памяти жрет меньше

Comment: Если они одинаковые то V8 скорее всего просто создаёт указатель, а не копирует все данные.

Comment: C таким анамнезом действительно проще всего написать разрабам V8, думаю. Вероятность того, что здесь ответят, далеко ненулевая, но если хотите оперативный комптентный ответ - проще всего будет обратиться в нужный mailing list.

Comment: @etki я затрудняюсь сформулировать это на английском, а так вы конечно правы

Comment: Скорее всего это https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2869 - V8 использует string slices для представления подстрок - когда JS код делает подстроку то символы не копируются, а просто делается маленька оберточка указывающая на оригинальную строку. см также мой пост http://mrale.ph/blog/2016/11/23/making-less-dart-faster.html

Comment: @Vyacheslav да, похоже это оно самое и есть. Спасибо

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov Если запустить ноду с параметром `--nostring_slices`, то график потребления памяти процессом несколько меняет свою форму, но в итоге оно все равно падает по нехватке памяти в районе 85000 ссылок. Так что дело, скорее всего, в чем-то другом.

Comment: @Yaant: `--nostring-slices` на самом деле не отключает их полностью, потому что SubString stub вшита в снапшот с включенными слайсами.  Если хочется их отключить, то нужно собирать ноду из сорцов и отключать их в `v8/src/flag-definitions.h` перед сборкой, тогда снапшот будет содержат "правильный" stub.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov таких тонкостей не знал. Спасибо :)